# Terminal symbol and non-terminal symbol

Tags: java

could anyone tell me the difference between Terminal and non-terminal symbol in the case of Java?

Does Terminal mean a Keyword and non-terminal any common string literal?

Comment: I agree with Stephan202 that your question is unclear. Can you give us the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In grammars, a terminal is some form of token (keyword, identifier, symbol, literal, etc.) whilst a non-terminal reference rules.

So both a keyword and a literal string would be terminals. A statement would be non-terminal.

(That's probably a really bad description. Read the dragon book.)

EDIT (not by original answerer): I'd never heard of the dragon book, so here's [a reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather unclear. Are you talking about the [formal grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) which describes the Java language? If so, *everything* you see in a syntactically valid Java file is (part of) a terminal.

> *A string is 'in' the language described
>   by some grammar if it can be produced
>   by applying the production rules of
>   the grammar until only terminals
>   remain.*

Perhaps you should check out the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/),